# Uniqueness of JSJ deformation space when there are no QH vertices

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $\mathcal{A}$ a collection of subgroups closed under conjugation and taking subgroups.

I'm interested in the problem of classifying all deformation spaces of JSJ decompositions of $G$ over subgroups in $\mathcal{A}$. Can it ever happen that the deformation space is unique? Perhaps if $G$ is such that any splitting of $G$ over $\mathcal{A}$ does not contain any quadratically hanging vertices (in the sense of Guirardel-Levitt)?

Comment: The question isn't clear. For a given $G$ and $\mathcal{A}$, there is one deformation space of JSJs, namely the one defined by Guirardel and Levitt: the space of maximal, universally elliptic $G$-trees. Are you varying $\mathcal{A}$ and wondering how the deformation space changes?  Or are you wondering about situations in which the deformation space is a single point?... (tbc)

Comment: I think Generalised Baumslag--Solitar groups, as studied by Forester, provide examples of groups with interesting (i.e. not just a point) deformation spaces of JSJ decompositions despite having no quadratically hanging vertices; indeed, all the vertex groups are cyclic. See §I.3.5 of Guirardel--Levitt's monograph, which refers to Forester's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110176 .

Comment: Apologies for making myself unclear. In my question, $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of  subgroups containing edge stabilisers of the splitting. So for instance, if $\Sigma$ is a large enough closed surface, $G = \pi_1(\Sigma)$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of cyclic subgroups of $G$, then any two non-isotopic pair of pants decompositions of $\Sigma$ induce two cyclic splittings which live in two distinct deformation spaces (which are singletons).

Comment: Even if $\mathcal{A}$ is only allowed to contain cyclic subgroups, I don’t think this ever happens unless every cyclic splitting of $G$ is trivial. If $T$ is a non-trivial $G$-tree, then taking $\mathcal{A}$ to contain $\langle g\rangle$ where $g$ acts hyperbolically on $T$ will force $T$ not to appear in the deformation space relative to $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Are you asking the groups in $\mathcal A$ to be slender or are you considering more general edge groups? Not much is known when the edge groups are not slender.

Comment: @HJRW ah of course, thank you. Sorry, I fundamentally misunderstood a part of the definition. It is clear to me now why there should only ever be one non-trivial deformation space.

Comment: Happy to have helped clear up any confusion!